# WAStorageEmulator.exe Load Interval failed

Tags: azure

I'm getting this issue on Windows 7 Pro 64 bits. My Compute Emulator works just fine.

Running through **Windows Azure Storage Command Line** as an Administrator. I'm an administrator on that computer.

I ran:

> WAStorageEmulator.exe -server MyServer -sqlinstance MyInstance -forcecreate -inprocess

and that worked. I can see the new database in SQL Server Express 2012.

Then I ran:

> WASStorageEmulator.exe start -inprocess

within the very same window (got to have the same privilege).

I'm getting:

> 5/25/2014 4:46:06 PM [Info_debug] BlockBlob: Load Interval failed. IsGC: True, Exception at System.Number.ParseDouble(String value, NumberStyles options, NumberFormatInfo numfmt)
>
> at Microsoft. WindowsAzure. DevelopmentStorage.Store.BlockBlobGarbageCollector. GetTimerIntervalOrDefault(Boolean isGC)
>
> 5/25/2014 4:46:06 PM [Info_debug] BlockBlob: Load Interval failed. IsGC: False,Exception    at System.Number.ParseDouble(String value, NumberStyles options, NumberFormatInfo numfmt)
>
> at Microsoft. WindowsAzure. DevelopmentStorage.Store.BlockBlobGarbageCollector. GetTimerIntervalOrDefault(Boolean isGC)

and later in the same error trace. (maybe a side effect of this error):

> 5/25/2014 4:46:06 PM [Error] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

I have rebooted. I have closed SQL Server. I made sure SQL Server Service is running.

Comment: Ok, had the same issue [Found link to this blog](http://blog.smarx.com/posts/windows-azure-storage-emulator-the-process-cannot-access-the-file-because-it-is-being-used-by-another-process) via this [Stack overflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23318350/azure-storage-emulator-error-and-does-not-start) Basically Port 10000 is already in use by another app!