# The listener for function was unable to start. Azure.Storage.Blobs: Service request failed

Tags: azure-functions

I have an Azure Function project containing both normal and timer functions. The timer function stopped working all of a sudden with error - `The listener for function 'Function1' was unable to start. Azure.Storage.Blobs: Service request failed.`.

As part of troubleshooting, I created a sample Azure Function project, which also has same problem. Below listed is the complete log from console.

```
Azure Functions Core Tools
Core Tools Version:       4.0.4895 Commit hash: N/A  (64-bit)
Function Runtime Version: 4.13.0.19486

[2022-12-05T05:39:46.886Z] Found C:\Visual Studio 2022\Projects\FunctionApp2\FunctionApp2\FunctionApp2.csproj. Using for user secrets file configuration.

Functions:

        Function1: timerTrigger

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2022-12-05T05:39:49.681Z] The listener for function 'Function1' was unable to start.
[2022-12-05T05:39:49.682Z] The listener for function 'Function1' was unable to start. Azure.Storage.Blobs: Service request failed.
[2022-12-05T05:39:49.683Z] Status: 400 (The value for one of the HTTP headers is not in the correct format.)
[2022-12-05T05:39:49.683Z] ErrorCode: InvalidHeaderValue
[2022-12-05T05:39:49.684Z]
[2022-12-05T05:39:49.684Z] Headers:
[2022-12-05T05:39:49.685Z] Server: Azurite-Blob/3.14.1
[2022-12-05T05:39:49.685Z] x-ms-error-code: InvalidHeaderValue
[2022-12-05T05:39:49.686Z] x-ms-request-id: 9d066414-f486-4f91-8b1a-a1f7b5ee9641
[2022-12-05T05:39:49.686Z] Date: Mon, 05 Dec 2022 05:39:49 GMT
[2022-12-05T05:39:49.687Z] Connection: keep-alive
[2022-12-05T05:39:49.687Z] Keep-Alive: REDACTED
[2022-12-05T05:39:49.688Z] Content-Length: 0
[2022-12-05T05:39:49.689Z] .
```

I checked the status of `AzureStorageEmulator` in location `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator`. The status is `IsRunning=False` (screenshot added below):

[image: status]

I tried `init` and `start` on AzureStorageEmulator and got below error:

[image: init and start]

Below is how the settings looks like

[image: config]

I read through similar issues but none of the solution resolved the issue. Did anyone faced similar issues? Can anyone please suggest what could be the potential issue here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure you have the correct blob connection string format and permission. If you can share the connection string format by removing confidential information from it, I can confirm the format.

Comment: I have updated the post with image from local settings. Hope that helps.

Comment: Same issue. Reboot worked. Seems that some other process was preventing the emulator to start on the expected ports.

Answer (score 3):

In the first screenshot, it can be seen that Storage Emulator Objects running on port number `10000`.
When it is using by some other process, then either we need to start the Storage Emulator in new port number or [kill](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39633428) the existing process running with that port number.

You can find which process is using the port number `10000` using the cmdlet in Command prompt:
[image]

In the Same Command prompt, after killing the process or if the process port 10000 is in idle state, run this cmdlet: `netsh http add iplisten 127.0.0.1`

Now, Open the Azure Storage Emulator Command Prompt in the system and then run the below cmdlets in the same order:

```
AzureStorageEmulator.exe start -inprocess
```

(OR)
If the above cmdlet is running indefinitely, then stop using `Ctrl + C` and then run the below cmdlet to start the storage emulator

```
AzureStorageEmulator.exe start
```

Refer to this SO [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23318350) for similar issue resolutions regarding the Azure Storage Emulator Start Issues for running the applications.

Answer (score 3):

Use MS Azure Storage Explorer, go to Azure Emulator/Blob Containers and delete all from there.
Rebuild and run your project in VS

[image]

Comment: This did not solve the problem for me.

Comment: Came across this post with a similar issue where running the function locally resulted in the emulator error "The listener for function XXXXXXX was unable to start. Azure.Storage.Blobs: Service request failed" and a 500 error code.  Deleting the container like this fixed it.