# Azure function: function unable to start

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

i have two azure functions type timer that untile few days ago works correctly. I did not change anything in the code..is the same as the previous week. Today i was going to start the project to test the interaction with API but the funciotns didn't start and throw this error.
I tried to put a debug point at the start of the function but debug doesn't start, throw immediatly this error without entering in the function. What is the problem??What should i do?

As i said i don't think is a code problem so if it is not necessary i will not post it.

[image]

this is my local.settings.json :
[image]

**[EDIT]** Error as text:

```
For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2023-04-03T11:00:08.960Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000029601DB'.
[2023-04-03T11:00:28.905Z] The listener for function 'WeeklyUpdateStandings' was unable to start.
[2023-04-03T11:00:28.908Z] The listener for function 'WeeklyUpdateStandings' was unable to start. Azure.Storage.Blobs: Service request failed.
[2023-04-03T11:00:28.913Z] Status: 500 (Internal Server Error)
[2023-04-03T11:00:28.915Z]
[2023-04-03T11:00:28.917Z] Headers:
[2023-04-03T11:00:28.919Z] Server: Azurite-Blob/3.19.0
[2023-04-03T11:00:28.921Z] x-ms-creation-time: Tue, 21 Mar 2023 13:05:03 GMT
[2023-04-03T11:00:28.922Z] ETag: "0x1F823F265BF6F90"
[2023-04-03T11:00:28.924Z] x-ms-blob-type: BlockBlob
[2023-04-03T11:00:28.928Z] x-ms-lease-state: available
[2023-04-03T11:00:28.931Z] x-ms-lease-status: unlocked
[2023-04-03T11:00:28.932Z] x-ms-client-request-id: 33215f58-4617-40bb-b83d-c2cbfc569778
[2023-04-03T11:00:28.934Z] x-ms-request-id: 5f791a85-41f1-466f-897e-bd6a304e3d0f
[2023-04-03T11:00:28.937Z] x-ms-version: 2021-10-04
[2023-04-03T11:00:28.939Z] Accept-Ranges: bytes
[2023-04-03T11:00:28.940Z] Date: Mon, 03 Apr 2023 11:00:28 GMT
[2023-04-03T11:00:28.947Z] x-ms-server-encrypted: true
[2023-04-03T11:00:28.949Z] x-ms-blob-content-md5: ju8YOCtSeTzOodG9Hn2PtA==
[2023-04-03T11:00:28.951Z] Connection: keep-alive
[2023-04-03T11:00:28.953Z] Keep-Alive: REDACTED
[2023-04-03T11:00:28.955Z] Last-Modified: Tue, 21 Mar 2023 13:05:03 GMT
[2023-04-03T11:00:28.957Z] Content-Length: 127
[2023-04-03T11:00:28.963Z] Content-Type: application/octet-stream
[2023-04-03T11:00:28.965Z] Content-MD5: ju8YOCtSeTzOodG9Hn2PtA==
```

**[EDIT]** if i start a new project with a simple azure function it works correctly

**[EDIT]** in the new project, if i copy the functions and start it, works correctly. How is it possible?

Comment: Did you install a new version of Azurite? I believe the error is coming from there.

Comment: Would this solve the issue? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/698846/listener-for-azure-function-was-unable-to-start-er

Comment: i don't think, cause when i closed this project, i did not update or install anything. How do I check which version of Azurite I have?

Comment: How can i check if storage emulator is running?

Comment: Could you provide your error message in the form of text instead of images because if any user faces similar issue in the future, it will be difficult to identify the similar issues and solutions in the forum.

Comment: Please check the similar [issue-resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74684009/the-listener-for-function-was-unable-to-start-azure-storage-blobs-service-requ) provided by the User @Pravallika

Comment: @DasariKamali but here there is an error 404....in my case is 500....is there any difference?

Comment: "Regardless of the error code, I observed the specific error `The listener for function 'Function1' was unable to start. Azure.Storage.Blobs: Service request failed` where that thread contains the solution for this error message. Hope it helps you.

Comment: Any update on the issue-resolution?

Comment: Seems like i don't have AzureStorageEmuator installed. I followed steps until it says to open "Azure Storage Emulatore Command Prompt" but i don't have it.

Comment: Get installed the Azurite Storage Emulator if you are using VS Code and different options also available like npm, Docker Hub etc in this [MS Site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azurite?tabs=visual-studio)

Comment: I installed azurite through npm and when i try to start it says: port already used. 
So, there is a process that use that port..but i followed the steps of the suggested answer thinking it can be helpfull so i missed something to remove this process that uset the same port. It would be a solution to change the port of blob services??

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is a global solution for every case but...
I found wich process was listening to the same port of the blob services and kill it. After the installation through npm of azurite i started it and when i run the project it works correctly. So in conclusion, why another process take control over the port 10000 instead of Azure Blob Services, that in the previous days use the same port normally??

Steps:

1. netstat -ano | find "10000"
2. kill the process that use the port : taskkill/F /PID 21500
3. if not installed, in packet manager : npm install -g azurite
4. run azurite: azurite --silent --location c:\azurite --debug c:\azurite\debug.log

but i don't understand why visual studio doesn't lauch azureite automatically like alway did last week.

Answer (score 0):

> but I don't understand why visual studio doesn't launch azurite automatically like always did last week.

Visual Studio will launch the Azurite Storage emulator automatically but that emulator should be in running mode in the system.

To make that, you can either run the Azure executable file or from the command line before opening the Visual Studio.

You can find the process of running the Azurite Storage emulator from this [section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azurite?tabs=visual-studio#run-azurite) of Microsoft Document.

But if the port is using by any other process, then you need to do the steps like you did in your solution either killing the existing process to make the port open/free or changing the port - Steps Reference: [44976890](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44976890/how-to-run-azure-function-app-on-a-different-port-in-visual-studio)