# Azurite Error: "Exit Due to Unhandled Error" when Running Azure Function Project

Tags: azure-functions, azurite

Good day fellow developer,

I would like to ask for help regarding running my Azure Function project using Visual Studio 2022.

Here's what happened, just after our Visual Studio 2022 was updated by our IT admin, we can no longer run our Azure Function project. When running the command: `"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Azure Storage Emulator\azurite.exe"` we encounter the following error: "Exit due to unhandled error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use 127.0.0.1:10001".
See screenshot below:[image]

I have already tried some solutions listed in this link [Azure Storage Emulator error and does not start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23318350/azure-storage-emulator-error-and-does-not-start), but we can't try the solutions that involve running CMD as an "Administrator" since our IT admin is the only one with access.

Comment: I know that `Run as Administrator` is not allowed in some organizations. Can you check you get this option "Run with Elevated privileges" on right click on command prompt - https://i.imgur.com/gbuaRxc.png. If this option available, that is similar to administrator which allows you to do some kind of operations.

Comment: Is the option "Run as administrator" not allowed only for Command prompt. If no, try with this Azure Command Prompt available to download (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli-windows?tabs=azure-cli)

Comment: Hello @HarikaReddy, thanks but unfortunately I don't have that option on my end :(
Also, we are not allowed to download any application on our own unless we requested it from our IT admin. I've tried to download the link you provided, but I need Admin access to install it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following steps resolved my issue:

1. Create a local storage accounts from Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer application. Customized the ports of the following: Blobs, Queues, and Table. See sample below:

[image]

2. Initialize the ports for the newly created storage accounts.

   *C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Azure Storage Emulator\azurite.exe"  --blobPort 20000 --queuePort 20001 --tablePort 20002 --silent --location c:\azurite --debug c:\azurite\debug.log*

see reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azurite?tabs=visual-studio%2Cblob-storage

Answer (score 1):

The reason of this error is there could be an instance running in the same port and if the new process tries to use the same port it leads to this error.

Initially, I got the same error when trying to run Azurite in the command prompt:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Azure Storage Emulator\azurite.exe"
```

[image]

Resolution:
I ran below commands to kill the process which is using the *10000*.

```
1. netstat -ano | findstr :10000

2. taskkill /PID <process_id> /F
```

[image]

I could run Azurite now with the command:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Azure Storage Emulator\azurite.exe"
```

[image]

Comment: Hello @PravallikaKV, the user is also asking that some of the commands involving Command Prompt as administrator. Can you clarify by adding this point in the Answer whether "Run as administrator" of command prompt for the given commands is not required to solve the issue.

Comment: Hi @PravallikaKV, I've tried your solution, but it seems that it will only work if I am in Administrator mode. I encountered the following error: 'ERROR: The process with PID 19096 could not be terminated. Reason: Access is denied.' Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue without using the Admin mode? Thanks!

Comment: @Eduwow, did you try cancelling the process running in Task Manager?

Comment: We were not allowed to cancel the running process since it is a part of the company apps.

Answer (score 0):

I haven’t used Azurite, and this may be a bit stupid, but I think the error happens because Azurite Queue service is running on the same port of something else, as stated in the log. Maybe you can try changing the port/address for this service to another one?

Comment: Hi, may I request a suggestion on how to update the ports without the need of changing into Admin mode? Thanks in advance.